# Trouble Combining two SELECT Statements

Tags: sql, select

I am sure there is some easy fix to this.  I just have basically no experience with writing SQL statements and so I don't know all of the commands, tricks or syntax to get what I need.

I have the following two SQL `SELECT` statements I need to combine:

**1:**

```
SELECT 
    h.jhhold, h.jhjob, h.jhrev, o.jadesc, o.jaoqty, o.jacqty, o.japo, o.javend  
FROM 
    Jhead AS h  
LEFT JOIN 
    jjops AS o ON h.jhjob = o.jajob  
WHERE 
    h.jhpcmp = 0 
    AND o.jatype = 2 
    AND o.jacqty < o.jaoqty 
    AND o.japcmp = 0 
    AND o.japo = 0
```

**2:**

```
SELECT 
    h.jhhold, h.jhjob, h.jhrev, o.jadesc, o.jaoqty, o.jacqty, o.japo, o.javend, 
    p.hdprcd, p.hdrecd, p.hdseq  
FROM 
    Jhead AS h 
LEFT JOIN 
    jjops AS o ON h.jhjob = o.jajob   
LEFT JOIN 
    hpodt AS p ON h.jhjob = p.hdjob   
WHERE 
    h.jhpcmp = 0 
    AND o.jatype = 2 
    AND o.jacqty < o.jaoqty 
    AND o.japcmp = 0 
    AND p.hdjob = h.jhjob 
    AND p.hdpo = o.japo 
    AND p.hdseq = o.jaseq
```

Both of these two statements return the results I need.  The first statement basically returns results where o.japo = 0 (it is never null).  The second returns a result where o.japo is not zero and then I attempt to join another table to the data.  I did try stick a UNION ALL in between but all union examples I looked up did not have unqiue WHERE statement per select statement.

.
I had initially attempted the following statement (below) but was getting multiple lines of data when o.japo = 0 and I could not figure out why it was picking up the extra lines but I suspect it was the second left join joining incorrect/unwanted data.  When o.japo = 0 all of the hpodt (p.) fields should have been null but instead were populated with data from somewhere.

```
SELECT h.jhhold, h.jhjob, h.jhrev, o.jadesc, o.jaoqty, o.jacqty, o.japo, o.javend, p.hdprcd, p.hdrecd, p.hdseq 
FROM Jhead AS h 
LEFT JOIN jjops AS o ON h.jhjob = o.jajob 
LEFT JOIN hpodt AS p ON h.jhjob = p.hdjob 
WHERE (h.jhpcmp = 0 AND o.jatype = 2 AND o.jacqty < o.jaoqty AND o.japcmp = 0 AND p.hdjob = h.jhjob AND o.japo != 0 AND p.hdpo = o.japo AND p.hdseq = o.jaseq AND o.jaopr != 'PT') OR (h.jhpcmp = 0 AND o.jatype = 2 AND o.jacqty < o.jaoqty AND o.japcmp = 0 AND o.japo = 0 AND o.jaopr != 'PT')
ORDER BY h.jhjob, o.jaseq, p.hdrecd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a `UNION` between the two statements.

UNION needs to have the same number of columns, so you'll need to do a little extra work.

Add a few nulls to the first select statement to cover the columns that don't exist.

```
SELECT 
   -- Common to both tables
   h.jhhold, h.jhjob, h.jhrev, 
   o.jadesc, o.jaoqty, o.jacqty, 
   o.japo, o.javend, 
   -- These columns don't exist here.
   -- include them anyway as NULL
   NULL as hdprcd,
   NULL AS hdrecd, 
   NULL AS hdseq  
FROM Jhead AS h  
LEFT JOIN 
  jjops AS o ON h.jhjob = o.jajob  
WHERE 
    h.jhpcmp = 0 
AND o.jatype = 2 
AND o.jacqty < o.jaoqty 
AND o.japcmp = 0 
AND o.japo = 0
-- The big boy, combining the results of two queries
---
UNION
SELECT 
   h.jhhold, h.jhjob, h.jhrev, 
   o.jadesc, o.jaoqty, o.jacqty, 
   o.japo, o.javend, p.hdprcd, 
   p.hdrecd, p.hdseq  
FROM Jhead AS h 
LEFT JOIN 
   jjops AS o 
ON h.jhjob = o.jajob   
LEFT JOIN 
   hpodt AS p 
ON h.jhjob = p.hdjob   
WHERE 
    h.jhpcmp = 0 
AND o.jatype = 2 
AND o.jacqty < o.jaoqty 
AND o.japcmp = 0 
AND p.hdjob = h.jhjob 
AND p.hdpo = o.japo 
AND p.hdseq = o.jaseq
```

Comment: Caution is advised using `UNION` - it sorts and removes duplicate rows. `UNION ALL` would be preferable here.

Comment: I assumed that was the intent here.

Comment: I just went through all the data and it looked great.  This worked and was easy to understand.  Thanks! The 'Union' still gave me the data I desired.

Comment: In this case the UNION and UNION ALL pulled the same results.

Comment: Hmm I am stuck because I have now tried to add a text field to the query _The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable._

Answer (score 1):

Join again to the `jjops`, using a different alias, then from that to `hpodt` :

```
SELECT 
    h.jhhold, h.jhjob, h.jhrev, 
    o.jadesc, o.jaoqty, o.jacqty, o.japo, o.javend,
    o2.jadesc, o2.jaoqty, o2.jacqty, o2.japo, o2.javend, 
    p.hdprcd, p.hdrecd, p.hdseq
FROM Jhead AS h  
LEFT JOIN
    jjops AS o ON h.jhjob = o.jajob  
LEFT JOIN
    jjops AS o2 ON h.jhjob = o2.jajob   
LEFT JOIN
    hpodt AS p ON h.jhjob = p.hdjob
    AND p.hdpo = o2.japo
    AND p.hdseq = o2.jaseq
    AND p.hdjob = h.jhjob
WHERE 
    h.jhpcmp = 0 
    AND o.jatype = 2 
    AND o.jacqty < o.jaoqty 
    AND o.japcmp = 0 
    AND o.japo = 0;
```

Note also that I've moved some of the conditions up into the `ON` clause. You can always move them back to the where clause if you want:

```
...
LEFT JOIN
    hpodt AS p ON h.jhjob = p.hdjob
WHERE 
    h.jhpcmp = 0 
    AND o.jatype = 2 
    AND o.jacqty < o.jaoqty 
    AND o.japcmp = 0 
    AND o.japo = 0
    AND p.hdpo = o2.japo
    AND p.hdseq = o2.jaseq
    AND p.hdjob = h.jhjob;
```

however it may produce different results - this last version will not allow the `LEFT JOIN` to return rows from `o2` that don't have rows from `p`.

Comment: Your first result gave me a lot of duplication it appears a line for every o2.jaseq, I think the o.jatype = 2 was not applying as I needed it to.  Paul Taylors reponse seemed to get me what I needed.  Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adjusting your Where clause on the original statement as well.

It may be better to avoid multiple selects against the same table if you don't have too.

```
SELECT h.jhhold, h.jhjob, h.jhrev, o.jadesc, o.jaoqty, o.jacqty, o.japo, o.javend, p.hdprcd, p.hdrecd, p.hdseq 
FROM Jhead AS h 
LEFT JOIN jjops AS o ON h.jhjob = o.jajob   
LEFT JOIN hpodt AS p ON h.jhjob = p.hdjob   
WHERE h.jhpcmp = 0 
    AND o.jatype = 2 
    AND o.jacqty < o.jaoqty
    AND o.japcmp = 0
    AND (o.japo = 0 
        OR (p.hdjob = h.jhjob AND p.hdpo = o.japo AND p.hdseq = o.jaseq 
                  AND o.japo <> 0))
```

Comment: This still appears to be giving me the same problem m initial statement gave me.  All of the selects to the hpodt table keep pulling non-null results for p.hdprcd, p.hdrecd, p.hdseq.  It is joining incorrect data for some reason.

Comment: I think changing the left join on hpodt to a left join a select statement that included the condition that o.japo <> 0 would get rid of those records Something like                                                              `left join (select [fields] from jhead as h left join jjops as o on ... left join hpodt as p on .. Where o.japo <> 0) AS MYData`

Comment: Alright I edited the SQL above that should work for you.  You need to add `o.jao <> 0` to the **OR** statement that has to do with your second select this will remove this should remove the duplicate records you were getting.